# How can I distribute workload between multiple MongoDB watchers for the same collection?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I wonder if it is possible to start multiple watchers for a collection?

In my case, I start multiple threads monitoring a collection, but the mongo returns the same document to all watchers.

How do I get MongoDB to split the document load between these started threads?

Thread Starter:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
                ThreadMongoDB thWork = new ThreadMongoDB(_config, _serviceProvider);
                thWork.ThreadName = "TH-" + i.ToString();

                Thread th = new Thread(thWork.Process);

                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    th.Start();
                });
    }
```

Code in class ThreadMongoDB:

```
public class ThreadMongoDB
    {
        readonly IMongoDatabase _db;
        readonly Executer _exec;

        public string ThreadName { get; set; }


        public ThreadMongoDB(IConfiguration iconfig, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var typeConn = iconfig["TypeConn"];
            var client = new MongoClient(iconfig[$"{typeConn}:cnnMain"]);
            _db = client.GetDatabase(iconfig[$"{typeConn}:dbMain"]);

            _exec = new Executer(iconfig, serviceProvider);
        }

        public void Process()
        {
            var options = new ChangeStreamOptions() { FullDocument = ChangeStreamFullDocumentOption.UpdateLookup };

            var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<ChangeStreamDocument<WorkerQueue>>()
                .Match("{ operationType: { $in: [ 'replace', 'insert', 'update' ] }}");
                //.Match("{ $or: [ {operationType: 'replace' }, { operationType: 'insert' }, { operationType: 'update' } ] }");

            using (var pilotQueueStream = _db.GetCollection<WorkerQueue>("one_queue_pilot")
                .Watch(pipeline, options).ToEnumerable().GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    pilotQueueStream.MoveNext();

                    WorkerQueue currentReg = pilotQueueStream.Current.FullDocument;

                    if (currentReg != null)
                    {
                        if (!currentReg.boolDone)
                        {
                           _exec.Execute(ThreadName, currentReg);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if it is possible to start multiple watchers for a collection?
>
> In my case, I start multiple threads monitoring a collection, but the mongo returns the same document to all watchers.

This outcome is expected: you can have multiple change streams active, but each stream is independent and there is no coordination between watchers. Watching identical streams will result in identical events.

> How do I get MongoDB to split the document load between these started threads?

This requirement will have to be handled in your application.

If your watchers are doing significant processing for change stream events and you want to distribute the workload, a few approaches to consider are:

- Have a change stream watcher push events to a central [work/job queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_queue) so that multiple worker threads can claim and process jobs from the queue. This is a typical batch processing pattern.
- Have each watcher include a `$match` stage that filters a different subset of change stream events to process. This approach requires some planning to ensure events don't overlap, and is less scalable if some event types will need more workers than others.

Before implementing either approach, it would definitely be worth confirming that your workload requires more workers/threads.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Before implementing the watcher, I was reading this work queue with the find (). First command with multiple threads, but then I saw that these watchers would trigger the process without having to pool the collection.
So I will keep a single watcher, and if the volume goes up I go back to reading the collection with multiple threads.

Thank you very much.